# sharepoint 2007 access denied when accessing user profiles via ssp

Tags: windows, sharepoint-2007

Guys I have a really strange problem in regards to sharepoint mysites today I go into user profiles and properties in order to setup a property all of a sudden I get access denied. First off I know that I'm logged in with the correct account after the access denied I decided to click on personalization services and permissions I than get An unhandled exception occurred in the user interface.Exception Information: Cannot complete this action. I'm not seeing anything in the server application logs either. So have any of you guys seen this before is there some kind of way to grant a user account the manage profiles right permission using stsadm. BTW all other fucntions of the ssp are working fine so my question is if the user profiles and my sites of a ssp tanks how do you repair that portion of the ssp? BTW the user accounts that I'm using are site collection owners and also they have full control at the web application level. I actually ran across this interesting post but this does not really help my problem.

http://blog.tylerholmes.com/2008/09/access-denied-for-site-collection.html

Answer (score 0):

MOSS 2007 and WSS-SPS have different ways of storing the profiles.  I ran into a very similar problem.  This site help me figure out exactly what was wrong and fix it.

http://blah.winsmarts.com/2007-7-SharePoint_2007__All_you_ever_wanted_to_know_about_User_Profiles.aspx